# OrientDB: text searching using gremlin

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases, gremlin, pyorient

I am using OrientDB and the gremlin console that comes with.

I am trying to search a pattern in text property. I have Email vertices with ebodyText property. The problem is that the result of querying with SQL like command and Gremlin language is quite different.

If I use SQL like query such as:

`select count(*) from Email where eBodyText like '%Syria%'`

it returns 24.

But if I query in gremlin console such as:

`g.V.has('eBodyText').filter{it.eBodyText.matches('.*Syria.*')}.count()`

it returns none.

Same queries with a different keyword 'memo' returns 161 by SQL but 20 by gremlin.

Why does this behave like this? Is there a problem with the syntax of gremlin command? Is there a better way to search text in gremlin?

I guess there might be a problem of setting properties in the upload script which uses python driver 'pyorient'.
[Python script used to upload the dataset](https://github.com/romanegloo/cs505_proj2/blob/master/scripts/importCsv.py)

Thanks for your help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with 2.1.15 and I had no problem.

These are the records.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDITED**

I added some vertexes to my DB and now the `count()` is 11

**QUERY:**

```
g.V.has('eBodyText').filter{it.eBodyText.contains('Syria')}.count()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
==>11
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's interesting. My version is 2.1.13, but I don't think that's the problem. Should it be a text encoding problem? or length maybe?

Comment: I just reinstalled it, and having the same problem with 2.1.15. Let me know if you need more information, and thanks~!!

Comment: @NeoJi can you share all the results of the following query
select from Email where eBodyText like '%Syria%' and g.V.has('eBodyText').filter{it.eBodyText.matches('.*Syria.*')}?

Comment: That will be a long list of email body. I updated the screenshot with eBodyText limit 3. I am concerning that there might be a null object and filter stops iterating.

Comment: I manually add a new record in studio, and that one was found. I guess my script to upload dataset has some problem. I will add a link to the script also.

Comment: Instead of using matches, I used 'contains', and it worked. `it.eBodyText.contains('Syria')` returned 24. Would you add this to your answer?